# What are the pros and cons of using a named binary format as opposed to an unnamed one?

Tags: java, design, performance

I'm curious to know are there any advantages or disadvantages to creating a named binary format as opposed to an unnamed one? I can only think of a increase in the required disk space.

Roughly speaking a *named* binary format is a binary format in which you can identify the data parts by using their name (`int`, `byte`). The names are stored in the output file itself as well

Example difference in usage:

- unnamed: `input.nextByte(); input.nextInt();`
- named:   `input.getByte("name1"); input.getInt("name2");`

Comment: I think your question is too specific, and if there are no official docs clarifying that, your only chance to find this out is to ask Mr. Persson himself.

Comment: Yeah, now it's much better, but could you explain what "named" means? I doubt it's a common term since I've never heard of it elsewhere.

Comment: Roughly speaking it means that you can identify specific data (like `int`, `byte`) so instead of accessing the data like this `format.nextInt(); format.nextByte()` you have `format.getInt("name"); format.getByte("name")`.

Comment: Are those names stored in files?

Comment: @scriptin yes, they are but they might be compressed (as this question isn't about an specific format the compression method is unknown). Could they not be? (except the case where names are equal to types (e.g. for `byte` the name is `byte`))

Comment: What is the purpose of "name"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's just a example but it's meant to demonstrate in a more visual way the difference between an named and unnamed format (actually it demonstrates it usage but I think that's enough to make the point)

Comment: When you supply "name" to the `getInt()` method, what does that method do with the name you supplied?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it gets the corresponding value from a `Map` (`Dictionary` in C#) (it pre-read the file) and casts it to the given type (`int` in this case)

Comment: Oh, I see. `format` is a Java Map object, yes?  The advantage is that you can look up a particular tuple *directly.*  That's the whole point of using a Map.

Comment: Whatever.  You use it because it confers the benefits that a Map provides.  The `FormatFileReader` merely provides persistence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, that's the case

Comment: So the phrase "named binary format" is a bit of a misnomer, isn't it?  It's just a persistable map with methods that do a value lookup by name and perform a cast to the correct type at the same time.

Comment: I didn't think of it this way. I think it's generally an accurate description

Comment: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is you don't need to know the exact position and sequence of every piece of data in your file.  Your expected usage is wrong.  You wouldn't already know the data type and name when you got to that point in your input.  You'd first read a byte to see what data type you had, then the next two bytes to see the length of the name, then the name, then the data itself.  Then you'd put that into some sort of dictionary and continue reading.

This is a huge advantage when you're dealing with schemas that rapidly change.  Also when you want your data format to be semi-open for modders and mapmakers.  It also makes caching easier, as you don't have to write things out to disk in a strict order.

Comment: How does it help modders? If there are some mods installed and they always load in the same order doesn't that guarantee that they will always read the data in the same order and therefore have no problems even without names?

Comment: Having to always read it in the same order is not a benefit.  It makes it very fragile to changes, and requires those changes be communicated extremely precisely upon every revision to modders.

Comment: It also helps with diagnostics and debugging. You can create a dump of the data that actually makes sense, telling you what may be missing or superfluous.